# Security vulnerability with exec(), shell_exec(), curl_exec()

Tags: php, security, shell, curl, shell-exec

Occasionally, I use exec(), shell_exec(), and curl_exec().  Below are typical uses.  Assume that where ever I have a PHP variable in them (i.e. $html in the first one), there is a chance that the user has the ability to modify its content.

What should I be concerned about from a security vulnerability perspective?  Is escapeshellcmd() and escapeshellarg() the answer, and if so where should it be used?

```
$cmd='echo "html + '.$html.'" | htmldoc --format pdf > '.$filename;
$cmd='/usr/bin/convert '.$docs.' '.$filename;
$cmd='HOME='.$dir.'; /usr/bin/libreoffice3.5 --headless -convert-to pdf --outdir '.$dir.' '.$file_org;
$cmd='wget -O '.$file_org.' "'.$url.'"';
$cmd='/opt/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf "'.$url.'" '.$paramaters;
$cmd='/usr/bin/php -q '.$worker.' '.$session_id.' >/dev/null &';
exec($cmd);

$cmd='sendfax -n -m -w -i '.$id.' -o JohnDoe -D -S "hello@gmail.net" -s "us-leg" -f "'.$from.'" -d "'.$to.'" '.$doc_list;
$cmd = "faxstat -s | grep \"^$jid \"";
$output = shell_exec($cmd);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_GET['user_agent'] ? $_GET['user_agent'] : $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] );
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,array('aaa'=>$aaa,'bbb'=>$bbb));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: name temporary files in php code, not allow user to name the files, not use wget to pull a file, use libcurl,

Comment: Use libcurl instead of wget?

Comment: I wonder what happens if a user makes ``$html`` to be ``"; rm -rf /; echo "foo"``.

Comment: @user1032531 what you wonder about ? you can't download file using curl ?

Comment: @JonasWielicki.  I tried the following, and the directory wasn't created.  $cmd="echo \"<h1>Hello; mkdir /tmp/testing /; echo \"foo\"</h1>\" | htmldoc --format pdf > /tmp/new.pdf"

Comment: @eicto.  I thought you could download files using curl, and was just making sure that your advice was to use libcurl and not use wget.

Comment: @user1032531: Try to add a ``\"`` before the ``;`` and after the ``Hello`` and remove the one before ``</h1>``.

Comment: @JonasWielicki.  Yikes!  `$html='"; mkdir /tmp/hack; echo "<h1>foo';` hacked my code.  What do I do about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don’t validate and/or escape the input values properly, anyone can execute arbitrary commands on your system in behalf of the user that runs PHP.

For command arguments, there is [`escapeshellarg`](http://php.net/escapeshellarg). Make sure you escape the whole argument value, e.g.:

```
$cmd='echo '.escapeshellarg('html + '.$html).' | htmldoc --format pdf > '.escapeshellarg($filename);
$cmd='/usr/bin/convert '.escapeshellarg($docs).' '.escapeshellarg($filename);
// […]
$cmd='sendfax -n -m -w -i '.escapeshellarg($id).' -o JohnDoe -D -S "hello@gmail.net" -s "us-leg" -f '.escapeshellarg($from).' -d '.escapeshellarg($to).' '.escapeshellarg($doc_list);
```

Comment: Thanks Gumbo.  Would escapeshellcmd() be used to escape something like "echo" or "sendfax" (assuming they were variables, and why one would do this I have no idea)?  Does this apply to all three exec(), shell_exec(), and curl_exec()?

Comment: Also you should be aware that, if the user can control the filename, he can possibly just overwrite some of your scripts or everything else which is writable by the PHP user.

Comment: @user1032531 The manual page lists only `exec`, `system`, and the backtick operator. And since `shell_exec` is identical to the backtick  operator, it’s safe to use it for that function too. But `curl_exec` is different from these as it does not execute system commands. It should be safe the way you use it.