# Get Hostname from IP

Tags: php

I need to extract the hostname from my ip adress.I have tried this:

```
echo shell_exec('nslookup ' . $iper->Get_Ip())["Server"];
```

Basically it export everything i need,but i' unable to access the host ip.
It looks similar to this:

```
Server:     xxxxx
Address:    xxxxx

Non-authoritative answer:
xxxxxxxa    name = xxxxxx

Authoritative answers can be found from:
xx.in-addr.arpa nameserver = sec3.apnic.net.
xx.in-addr.arpa nameserver = ns3.lacnic.net.
xx.in-addr.arpa nameserver = tinnie.arin.net.
xx.in-addr.arpa nameserver = sns-pb.isc.org.
xx.in-addr.arpa nameserver = ns3.afrinic.net.
xx.in-addr.arpa nameserver = pri.authdns.ripe.net.
pri.authdns.ripe.net    internet address = xxxx
sec3.apnic.net  internet address = xxxxxxxx
sns-pb.isc.org  internet address = xxxxxx
tinnie.arin.net internet address = xxxx
pri.authdns.ripe.net    has AAAA address xxxx
sec3.apnic.net  has AAAA address xxxx
sns-pb.isc.org  has AAAA address xxxx
tinnie.arin.net has AAAA address xxxx
```

Is there a better aproach to get the host ,or i'l have to mess around with this way,and try somehow to extract the host ip....
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer,the only way which i could find to get the host from the ip was :

```
$data = (shell_exec('nslookup ' . $ip_adress));
```

Here is the working code that will return your host ip:

```
$iper = new IpEr();
$ip_adress = $iper->Get_Ip();

    $data = (shell_exec('nslookup ' . $ip_adress));
    $data = (explode("\n",$data));
    $data = explode(":",$data[0]);
    echo trim($data[1]);
```

And here is the iper class if someone needs it:

```
<?php

class IpEr{
  public function Get_Ip(){
    if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])){
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
    elseif(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])){
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    else{
      $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return  $ip;
  }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP has a built-in function for this, [`gethostbyaddr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyaddr.php).

```
<?php

class IpEr{
  public function Get_Ip(){
    if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])){
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
    elseif(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])){
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    else{
      $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return  $ip;
  }
}

$iper = new IpEr();
$ip_adress = $iper->Get_Ip();

echo gethostbyaddr($ip_adress);

?>
```

Also, as a general rule, it is not a good idea to use `shell_exec` and `exec` because it introduces potential security vulnerabilities

Comment: Can you explain it more please ,which security vulnerabilities?It return the host address in a different way  ,still i get the same result.I'd like to know jut the vulnerabilities?

Comment: Read this please :D http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13660685/security-vulnerability-with-exec-shell-exec-curl-exec

Comment: @Arslan.H I've updated my answer with complete code. The link you provided gives a basic idea of why it's not generally a good idea to use `exec`, it gives an attacker a potential way in to your system, it's not always insecure but it should be avoided if possible.

Comment: Still you didnt explain those potential security vulnerabilities

Comment: If you read somwhere that there is some vulnerabilities you have to stay behind it ,not just write it....

Comment: @Arslan.H There's nothing wrong with `exec` itself it's just that if an attacker is able to modify the value passed to it they can easily run commands on your system. For example, if you're passing user input to `exec` you need to make sure you escape it properly, as demonstrated in the link you posted.