# DNS Lookup in php with docker

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to make a program, that are able to DNS Lookup a website, it works fine. Now i wan't to run it in docker, but when try to dns lookup a website, i don't get any output.

```
<title>DNS LOOKUP</title>
<header>
<p>Do a DNS Lookup on any website!</p>
</header>
<form method="post" action="?action">
<input type="text" name="Host" placeholder="Host" />
<input type="submit" value="DNS Lookup" />  
</form>

<?php
  if(isset($_GET['action']))
  {

    $host = $_POST['Host'];
    $command = shell_exec("nslookup $host");
  }
  echo $command;

?>
```

Docker Compose file:

```
  version: '2'

  services:
     lookup:
        build: .
        ports:
           - '8888:80'
        stdin_open: true
        tty: true
        volumes:
           - ./source:/var/www/html
           - ./logs:/var/log/apache2
```

Docker File:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt update

RUN apt install -y \ 
   apache2 \  
   php \ 
   libapache2-mod-php \ 
   dnsutils

RUN useradd -d /home/chal/ -m -s /bin/nologin chal

WORKDIR /home/chal

COPY source .

USER chal

ENTRYPOINT service apache2 start && /bin/bash
```

Comment: What does your script produce if you type `google.com; ls -l /` into the form?  You should probably avoid the `shell_exec()` call entirely, rather than trying to debug this specific instantiation.

Comment: If i try to do command execution on it, it works, i know that i shouldn't use the shell_exec(), but i am making a challenge, where you shall use that vulnerability.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13660685/security-vulnerability-with-exec-shell-exec-curl-exec. But if you don't mind, its upto you.